# Rotate Interface only 180º

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, orientation

I just want to rotate my app aways 180º. So, I won't get it in portrait mode.

My code is like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return NO;
}
```

How can I do it?

**EDIT:**

I dont know why, but it stoped working. Any ideas? Even when i set `return YES`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but on of my TabBar items wasn't set with a NIB name. That's what was causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

That will make it so your view controller can only be in landscape orientations.  [`UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape()` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW45).

Comment: I put it, but is not working. I run it on iPad Simulator, and when i rotate to left twice, it still inverse.

Comment: @Lucas You have probably put the method in the wrong controller. Can you set a breakpoint, and check if it is called when the device is rotated?

Comment: Try on a device, as fas as I know, the simulator does not do upside-down.

Comment: @Lucas You need to insert this method into your view controller

Comment: But i am setting it. Its inside of my view controller. Not on App Delegate

Comment: Please? Im getting a little frustate here, hehe.

Comment: @Lucas Veiga: this is the code we use and it works for us. Without seeing more of your code, we can't help you any more.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of this method determines whether rotation to *interfaceOrientation* should be allowed. Therefore, you could check whether *interfaceOrientation* is landscape, and return YES only if so.

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
```

Comment: I put it, but is not working. I run it on iPad Simulator, and when i rotate to left twice, it still inverse.